# See cache's hit and misses

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I am using Hibernate and ehcache with second level cache enabled. I put @Cacheable on my User entity, like this:

```
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region = "usersCache")
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

...


}
```

But when I enable Hibernate's sql logging, I still see my `select * from users where userId = ?" query... I thought maybe this is normal behavior and the cache process is somehow transparent to Hibernate, which is just querying and then ehcache intercepts that and gets the data from the cache... so how can I see whether the query was a hit or miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable [Hibernate statistics generation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-statistics) be setting `hibernate.generate_statistics property to true`. Then you can monitor cache hit/miss count via `SessionFactory.getStatistics()`.

```
SessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics()
```

provides this information.

also can be seen through `JConsole`, refer [this](http://ehcache.org/documentation/operations/jmx).